# Is there a method to show string values instead of boolean with EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form where user needs to select the gender in a dropdown list, and I am using EditorFor() for this purpose, which is working well, but is displaying values as True and False, instead of Male, Female and Gender is a boolean property. How to convert boolean values into strings in this case. The code is as below:

```
<dl>
  <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeInfo.Person.Gender</dt>
  <dd>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeInfo.Person.Gender)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeInfo.Person.Gender)
   </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Why are you using boolean in first instance?

Comment: I seriously wonder why Gender would be boolean: is Female true or false? Also there are genders in between.

Comment: @PeterB it's an old software, and cannot make changes to the controllers and models side, I just want a fast solution for now, making the changes to the .cshtml file, though representing just something like Male, Female.

Comment: Better make it an Enum. Much easier and you can use the string value directly. Or `@(Model.EmployeeInfo.Person.Gender ? "Male" : "Female")`

Comment: @VDWWD great but, don't have access to model definitions.

Comment: Can you post your get action for creating the view  pls?